# Extracting data from Oracle database using GCP Dataflow beam job and python sdk

Tags: oracle, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam-io

I have a requirement to  extract A/P data from oracle database table and land it to GCS bucket daily. I prefer to use python sdk and apache beam but i could not find any connectors in beam library .
My requirement is very simple - read the table and  load the output in gcs bucket with minimal transformation.
Any advise on best approach

Thanks

Comment: Take a look to [Datastream](https://cloud.google.com/datastream). Still in Preview, but it fits perfectly for your use case

Comment: Hi Diego - Datastream is not approved by architecture team. Not sure if I can get jdbcio equivalent connector in Python beam sdk

Comment: Sorry, I'm only aware of the [Java JDBC](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-batch#java-database-connectivity-jdbc-to-bigquery) option :-/

Comment: @DiegoRodríguez's comment is the best answer. You can also ask your architecture team to reinvent the wheel, but there is low value to do that